# Лишний элемент при чтении из файла на С++

Tags: visual-c++, файлы, c++

Здравствуйте. Есть задача читать целые числа из файла и добавлять в конец линейного односвязного списка. Реализую чтение:

```
void createListFromFile(List &start)
{
    ifstream f("f.txt");
    deleteList(start);
    List p = new Node;
    start = p;
    while(!f.eof()){
        f >> p->inf;
        p->next = new Node;
        p = p->next;
    }
    p->next = NULL;
    f.close();
}
```

Реализую печать:

```
void printList(List start)
{
    if (!start) cout << endl << "Список пуст!"; else
        while (start)
        {
            cout << start->inf << "\t";
            start = start->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
}
```

В результате, если в файле n чисел, то на экран печатается n+1 и обязательно левое, например -842150451. Ясное дело, что он или читает одно лишнее пустое число и присваивает ему пустое(случайное) значение или печатает лишнее. Но я не могу найти ошибку. Прошу вашей помощи. Спасибо.

Comment: @embarcadero, с eof Вам подсказали (и я, конечно, понимаю, что программка тестовая), но если бы Вы проверяли **успешность ввода числа** (а вдруг там вместо цифры буква?), то ошибочку бы сами увидели раньше.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Очень распространенная ошибка. Тут дело в неправильной проверке конца файла. Флаг eof устанавливается не когда читается последний байт из файла, а после того, как произошла попытка прочитать за пределами файла. Т.е. вы читаете последний элемент, eof == false, далее пробуйте прочитать за пределам файла, eof==true, читается неизвестно что, заносится в список  и только тогда цикл прерывается.

Как делать. Проверять eof сразу после чтения и до занесения элемента в список, например, так.

```
while(true){
    f >> p->inf;
    if (f.eof()) break;
    p->next = new Node;
    p = p->next;
}
```

Или как написано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558907/c-i-o-dont-understand-why-there-is-1/8558959#8558959).

В связи с совершенно справедливым замечением @avp, всю функцию следует переписать примерно так

```
void createListFromFile(List &start)
{
    ifstream f("f.txt");
    if (!f.good()) return; //Можно выкинуть исключение
    deleteList(start);

    int temp;
    f >> temp;
    if (f.eof()) {
        start=NULL; //Если deleteList не обнуляет start
        f.close();
        return ;
    }

    List p = new Node;
    p->inf = temp;
    start = p;    

    while(true){
        f >> temp;
        if (f.eof()) break;
        p->next = new Node;
        p = p->next;
        p->inf = temp;
    }
    p->next = NULL;
    f.close();
}
```

Если где ошибся, извините, час поздний.

Comment: @mikillskegg, а все равно в последнем элементе будет каша. Узел надо добавлять в список не до, а после успешного чтения.

Comment: Ну, а у меня что?

Comment: Соглашусь с @avp. А потому что элемент сначала подшивается к списку, а потом заполняется переменная inf значением из файла.

Comment: Хотя на практике каши нету. Моя благодарность за 1 пример, второй отбрасывает последнее верное число)

Comment: Не знаю. Я проверил, у меня все правильно считывает. Где у тебя ошибка в другом месте.

Answer (score 4):

Проблема ясна. Смотрите, вы ведь *после* считывания каждого числа добавляете новый `Node`, в том числе и после последнего. В этом `Node` число будет, понятно, неверное.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте "заглядывать" на следующий символ с помощью peek(). Тогда и рекомендации уважаемого [@avp](/users/232/avp) по проверке символа сможете выполнить.